# Good materials / resources to start on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I've begun the migration of an ASP.NET MVC website to Windows Azure
I've already found some tutorials :

- [Windows Azure and SQL Azure Tutorials](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2138.windows-azure-and-sql-azure-tutorials-en-us.aspx)
- [Windows Azure - .NET Developer Center (Create your first application)](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/)

But I would like to have a more academical background, a general knowledge of the whole plateform.
Do you have some good books, websites, blogs or any other support to recommend ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I've went though a bunch of episodes of Cloud Cover on Channel9 when I started working with Azure. I felt that they went in depth on some topics. Gave some quick tips on other. It's a great resource.

Comment: have you tried the Windows Azure Platform Taining Kit - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396 ?

Comment: @Smetad Anarkist  Thank you, I'll watch those on Channel9 :  http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/windowsazure/learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patterns and practices group has several books available that give an overview of Windows Azure technology from different perspectives.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/08/17/microsoft-patterns-amp-practices-books-offer-guidance-on-adopting-windows-azure.aspx

I have been through the book Moving Applications to the Cloud book in particular. It is written to consider the perspectives of the business person, the IT pro and the developer. It was good to see the technology decisions from different points of view.

Buck Woody has a nice summary on his [blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/buck_woody/archive/2012/06/13/windows-azure-write-run-or-use-software.aspx) on when to leverage the different service platforms available in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

If you are very new to Windows Azure the following articles will create a knowledge base for you:

1. [Intro to Windows Azure](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/intro-to-windows-azure/)
2. [Understanding Cloud Storage](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/cloud-storage/)
3. [Hybrid Cloud Solution](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/hybrid-solutions/)

After that you would be ready to start developing you application and as you showed interest in .net development I would say visit the link below for all the .net related resources at once single place:

[Windows Azure .net Develop Center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/)

In the same page above, look for left side section name **"How to Guide"** for a list of common steps you are going to use in your daily development.

Comment: Thank you for these useful links